# Issue connecting SOAP through Postman

Tags: postman

I’m stuck with trying to connect to my SOAP API. The goal is to retrieve a quote via the “Getquote” function which is available in our webservice and use that quote in an application in Bubble.is. Therefore, I want to make it work through form-data so I can reuse the keys and values in Bubble. I get a succesfull quote through the raw method. See picture

Raw method:

[image]

You can see that all my fields are in the body so with the form-data method I put all the individual fields in key and value but I get the error message you see below.

Form data method:

[image]

Can someone see what I'm doing wrong? Excuses me for I am just starting. There might be some beginner mistakes in there. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

SOAP encodes messages by using XML. Form data uses a completely different encoding, which the SOAP server doesn't understand, hence the error.

Although I've never used it, there is a Chrome extension called [Boomerang](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/boomerang-soap-rest-clien/eipdnjedkpcnlmmdfdkgfpljanehloah?hl=en) that supports SOAP requests, and which may suit you better.

Comment: Hi Robert,

Thank you for message! My end goal is to integrate this in a bubble.is application. On the website they suggest to first get it working in postman and then in bubble. In bubble you have to fill in the parameters with keys and values. Do I understand it correct that XML doesnt work like that? In other words: such a set up will not work in Bubble? 

Arjuna

Comment: @ArjunaBosch I had to check what Bubble is, but unless you can get Bubble to make either raw or XML/SOAP requests, it might be difficult to get it working. If Bubble only supports key/value, that would suggests that it can only perform "regular" HTML form requests (form-data or url-encoded). But since I don't know Bubble I can't give a definitive answer.